# Is it collusion?

Tags: paper-submission, cheating, homework

Is it collusion to discuss your assignment after you and the other party have both submitted it?

A friend of mine and I want to discuss our assignment after we have both submitted it. The assessment is basically answering questions based on our lecturers and we just want to cross and compare but without cheating. Thus talking about it after our assignments have been submitted.

Is this wrong or unethical? Can it be considered collusion?

Comment: Do you really mean collusion? This is not a well defined term in the realm of academic misconduct. Could you clarify what exactly you mean, or do you mean is this academic misconduct in general?

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't be collusion unless there are some special circumstances. Collusion would be working together to prepare the assignment papers.

But, it is best to check with the professor on such things. If there is a follow up assignment or the opportunity to re-do the assignment for higher marks, then there might be an issue.

The professor has their own rules, generally, which might be more strict than the general understanding of such things. Check and be sure.